# How to initialize an array of TIME? in Java

Tags: java, arrays, datetime, calendar

I would like to have an array which holds a list of arrival times  of trains like this

### Arrival Times Array:

---

9.15

---

10.34

---

12.10

---

6.15

What would be the correct way to do it and i also want to sort them

Comment: Well which bit is confusing you - arrays, or which type to use for times? I would suggest using Joda Time (if you're using Java 7 or older) or java.time (if you're using Java 8). In both cases, you want the `LocalTime` class.

Answer (score 2):

Use class `java.util.Date`. The array declaration will look like

```
Date[] myDates = new Date[n];
```

where `n` is number of elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create `arraylist` like below snippet

```
import java.util.*;

List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<Calendar>(n); // initial size if not given it will grow dynamically.
dates.add( Calendar.getInstance() );
```

for you case to simple hold the  time of the trains you can use any arrays of the `float` or `double` like below
`float floatArray[] = new float[5]; //if size is fixed or else use arraylist` or
`double doublearray[]=new double[5];`